# Is there any good 1 session D&D stories for beginners?

Tags: dnd-5e, published-adventures, one-shot

I am hoping to organize a small D&D night for me and 3-4 of my friends, who are all new to the game. I bought the starter set so I already have characters (Level 1 to start, but modifiable) and dice, but, it came with the adventure "Lost Mine of Phandelver" and I am worried that it would be too long. As I assume  that we will only be able to go for one session (5-7 hours) as we do not have the opportunity to get together very often. I understand that this is a tall order, and I would be very grateful if you could help me out.

P.S. This is not a requirement but if the session could end up with them in a tavern somewhere near the beginning of the story, that would be great as it would be a nice gimmick to bring the drinks in. Again this is entirely optional. And again, I would very grateful for any help.

Comment: It seems this is D&D 5e, based on the adventure you mentioned. If it isn't, please retag accordingly with some other edition.

Comment: Any reason not to just run part 1 of that adventure? I ran it last night and it took about 4 hours. It comes to a relatively satisfying conclusion if you don't manage to get another session or several in.

Comment: @wax eagle Sorry about the tag and, also, there really isn't any reason not to, I just would've preferred to have an actual complete story.

Comment: Sorry, see the linked game-rec guidance in the post notice, this will be way too broad of a requirement as written (third parties are already dumping out 5e adventures).  Needs to be lots more specific or be a "how do I learn to fish" question.

Comment: Funny enough, I'm prepping a 1 shot beginners-to-roleplaying D&D adventure right now.  It'll probably be a month or two before I can put the notes into something beyond scrawls but yeah, this is a useful thing to have.